# how make ng-model work separately inside array of objects?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, checkbox

I'm stuck with some concept while realizing checkbox system.

I've got an array of objects, it looks like this:

```
this.columnsGroups = [
        {
           id: 1,
           title: 'General requests',
           props: [
              {
                title: 'Search level', 
                filterType: 'entry',
                visible: undefined
              },
              {
                title: 'ID',
                filterType: 'number',
                visible: undefined
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           id: 2,
           title: 'Technical Requests',
           props: [
              {
                title: 'Search level', 
                filterType: 'entry',
                visible: undefined        
              },
              {
                title: 'ID',
                filterType: 'number',
                visible: undefined
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           id: 3,
           title: 'Popular requests',
           props: [
              {
                title: 'Search level', 
                filterType: 'entry',
                visible: undefined
              },
              {
                title: 'ID',
                filterType: 'number',
                visible: undefined
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           id: 4,
           title: 'Misc requests',
           props: [
              {
                title: 'Search level', 
                filterType: 'entry',
                visible: undefined
              },
              {
                title: 'ID',
                filterType: 'number',
                visible: undefined
              }
           ]
        }
    ]
```

What I'm trying to do is to parse this array into html template with checkboxes.
The structure of the template consists of: parent checkbox

```
<div class="ln-select-columns-content" ng-if="currentTab.isAdvancedSearch" ng-repeat="group in ctrl.columnsGroups" ng-style="{'width':'25%'}">
  <div class="ln-select-column-row">
    <label>
      <span class="ln-checkbox">
                      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="allChecked" ng-checked="allSelected" ng-click="ctrl.toggleSelectAllAttributes()"/>
                      <span class="ln-bg"></span>
      </span>
      <div class="ln-select-column-name"><b>{{group.title}}:</b></div>
    </label>
    <div ng-repeat="column in group.props" class="ln-select-column-row">
      <label>
        <span class="ln-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="column.visible" />
                                <span class="ln-bg"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="ln-select-column-name">{{column.title}}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Literally, the template view looks like this:
[view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4bUU.png)

Now, the problem is: when I'm writing a realisation for checkboxing all the child checkboxes with parent checkbox for each column, `ng-model=allChecked` checks all the child checkboxes from any parent checkbox in the container.

What would be the best way to do parent checkboxing, isolated from the sibling parent checkboxes? 
Or maybe the array of objects is not correctly structured?

Comment: depends on your use case, this could be done even without `ng-model`, using `ng-checked` and pushing/poping objects into selected objects array.

Comment: remove plunker link from my answer and added SO snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify your JSON object a little bit by adding a `selected` property for tracking `ng-model` of each checkbox. Then you can write methods in your `$scope` to trigger on `ng-change` of each checkbox and toggle checkboxes by modifying JSON object.

For complete solution please see below snippet.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.toggleGroup = function(group) {
    if (group.selected) {
      group.props.forEach(function (prop) {
        prop.selected = true
      })
    } else {
       group.props.forEach(function (prop) {
        prop.selected = false
      })
    }
  }
  
  $scope.selectProp = function(group) {
    var allSelected = true;
    group.props.forEach(function (prop) {
      allSelected = allSelected && prop.selected;
    })
    group.selected = allSelected;
  }
  
  $scope.columnsGroups = [
        {
           id: 1,
           title: 'General requests',
           selected: false,
           props: [
              {
                title: 'Search level', 
                filterType: 'entry',
                visible: undefined,
                selected: false
              },
              {
                title: 'ID',
                filterType: 'number',
                visible: undefined,
                selected: false
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           id: 2,
           title: 'Technical Requests',
           selected: false,
           props: [
              {
                title: 'Search level', 
                filterType: 'entry',
                visible: undefined,
                selected: false     
              },
              {
                title: 'ID',
                filterType: 'number',
                visible: undefined,
                selected: false
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           id: 3,
           title: 'Popular requests',
           selected: false,
           props: [
              {
                title: 'Search level', 
                filterType: 'entry',
                visible: undefined,
                selected: false
              },
              {
                title: 'ID',
                filterType: 'number',
                visible: undefined,
                selected: false
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           id: 4,
           title: 'Misc requests',
           selected: false,
           props: [
              {
                title: 'Search level', 
                filterType: 'entry',
                visible: undefined,
                selected: false
              },
              {
                title: 'ID',
                filterType: 'number',
                visible: undefined,
                selected: false
              }
           ]
        }
    ]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="group in columnsGroups">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="group.selected" ng-change="toggleGroup(group)"/> {{group.title}}
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="prop in group.props">
          <input ng-change="selectProp(group)" ng-model="prop.selected" type="checkbox"/> {{prop.title}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <pre>
      {{columnsGroups | json}}
    </pre>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I've tested your piece of code and i've got couple of questions concerning it. 
First. According to your Angular.js you don't loop thru `code` $scope.columnsGroups

Comment: You take already objects as globally accessible from columnGroups. Is it okay?

Second, the property selected inside the props array is not necessary. "visible": undefined, - is the prop that defines visibility of these objects inside columnsGroups array. In my case, as you can see the screenshot, only bold-highlighted(parent) checkboxes are checked. 

Is it possible to transfer it instead of selected to visible property?

Comment: you can remove `selected` property and use `visible` instead. I guess, code should work just fine.

Comment: yeah, man! works! I thought i need to loop thru the columnsGroups array to make everything happen! 
But turned out it's possible to handle objects without entering an array